# Display a value in bar plot

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I generated this plot and I cannot display a value properly for each bar. Here is my bar plot:

[image]

This is my code for creating the above plot:

```
X_perc = [10, 7, 3, 5, 5]
cols = ['3.1-4.14', '4.14-5.18', '6.22-7.26', '7.26-8.3', '5.18-6.22']
data = np.array([[10, 7, 5, 5, 3],])

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
for i, (name, v) in enumerate(zip(cols, X_perc)):
    bottom=np.sum(data[:,0:i], axis=1)
    ax.bar(1,data[:,i], bottom=bottom, label="{}".format(name))
    ax.text(0.7, (v*i)/v * i + v + i, str(v), fontweight='bold')

plt.legend(framealpha=1)
plt.axis([-10, 10, 0, 31])
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          
    which='both',      
    bottom=False,      
    top=False,         
    labelbottom=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum of positions to annotate your stacked bars

```
positions = np.cumsum(data)

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
for i, (name, v) in enumerate(zip(cols, X_perc)):
    bottom=np.sum(data[:,0:i], axis=1)
    ax.bar(1,data[:,i], bottom=bottom, label="{}".format(name))
    ax.text(0.7, positions[i], str(v), fontweight='bold') # Use it here
```

[image]